# SearchView and toolbars

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

I want a menu item in my toolbar when clicked to act like a SearchView. I tried this, but the icon was still the default SearchView icon...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_edit_courses"
    android:title="@string/action_edit"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_delete_courses"
    android:title="@string/action_delete"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Please I don't know how to get through with it... Thank you in advance

Comment: So why can't you just use the one that comes with Android?

Comment: I want d icon to depict something else and not just a search but ive decided to go tru another route. Thanks so much